# CiviCRM encoding not working

Tags: encoding, printing, report, character, civicrm

I am trying to print Grant Report in CiviCRM, it's in UTF8.

Language: Georgian and this is what happens:

> áƒ“áƒáƒ®áƒ£áƒ áƒ£áƒšáƒ˜

What is wrong with it?

Comment: I suspect this question has a similar solution to http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9279/problem-displaying-diacritics-in-pdf-files